# How to get iPython to use Updated Egg/Module

Tags: python, module, egg

I've updated a Python egg that is only being used locally. The update proceeded correctly and installed into `/usr/lib/python2.5/site-packages/eggName-UpdatedVersionNumber-py2.5.egg`

However, when I open iPython and try to import the egg, I still get the old version.

Running egg_name.__file__ gives me:

> /usr/local/FOLDER/lib/python2.5/site-packages/eggName-OldVersionNumber-py2.5.egg/egg/__init__.pyc

Running easy_install --upgrade EGG shows:

> ... EGG UpdatedVersionNumber is
>   already the active version in
>   easy-install.pth\

Any idea on how to get the system to call the new version installed at /usr/lib/python2.5/site-packages/...?

Answer (score 1):

Note that you have 2 different `site-packages` locations; one is `/usr/lib/python2.5/site-packages` and the other is `/usr/local/FOLDER/lib/python2.5/site-packages`.

The egg in the latter location is being preferred over the egg in the first location when the latter location comes first in your `PYTHON_PATH`. In iPython, you can check the python path by printing `import sys; sys.path`; install the new egg in the second location to have iPython use it, or remove the old egg from that location altogether.

If you do this manually, don't forget to update the `.pth` file in the affected `site-packages` directory.